# is it possible change android application icon without updating application?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How do we change the Android application icon without updating the application like Amazon frequently do and Naukari did recently

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically changing the app icon in an Android project is not a straightforward task because the app icon is typically set in the AndroidManifest.xml file and is meant to be static. However, there are some workarounds you can use to achieve this effect.

One common approach is to create different launcher activities with their own icons and then dynamically switch between these activities.

Comment: I am using activity-alias and COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED and COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED with PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP but still, the application gets killed.  how to avoid killing apllication